# Does AWS S3 cache mp3 files to local?

Tags: amazon-s3, caching, audio-streaming

When I click the mp3 file's AWS S3 path, it plays in my browser, see screenshot below:
[image]

Is the mp3 downloaded/cached to my local machine? If so where is it? I tried to search for it in Chrome cache folder but did not find anything. Very curious how this works exactly.

Answer (score 1):

No, S3 doesn't cache any files locally. If a file were cached it's determined by your browser, who makes the decision based on a number of factors (such as HTTP headers, see [1]).

The reason the MP3 file plays in your browser is because your browser knows it can play the MP3 file and not just download it.

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
"The reason the MP3 file plays in your browser is because your browser knows it can play the MP3", yeah I get that. 

And my question now is that how is the mp3 played if it is not on my local machine? Thinking about how music streaming works in general, I would think the mp3 has to be at least buffered locally?

Comment: Well the file is being downloaded as you "open" the URL in your browser.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, thanks! So where would such downloaded file be stored on my local machine?